# Symfony Method to Turn Template to String

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony1

I use the Symfony PHP MVC framework.  I'm using JSON to pass an AJAX response, and I need an action's template HTML to be one of the values passed. Does Symfony have a method along the lines of renderTemplateToString() ?

Even for those unfamiliar with Symfony, is there an obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sfAction::getPartial()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_getpartial) and [`getComponent()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_getcomponent).