# Symfony render template to string

Tags: php, symfony1, rendering

Is there a way to get fully rendered template (with or without layout) as a string, within action?

i.e. something along these lines:

```
public function executeMyAction()
{
   $this->variable1 = 'foo';
   $this->variable2 = 'bar';

   // renders template using assigned variables, partials, layouts, etc. as if it was for    output to browser, but assigns html to string
   $renderedTemplate = $this->renderTemplateToString();
}
```

P.S. I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926041/symfony-method-to-turn-template-to-string), however the answer provided there isn't that good for my purposes. Links doesn't work and getPartial gets template file without rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should try [`sfController::getPresentationFor()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfController#method_getpresentationfor).